# Import custom-font in Laravel DOMPDF 0.8.3 / Laravel 5.8

Tags: dompdf, custom-font, laravel-5.8

I try to import my custom-font VAGRounded_BT.ttf in Laravel Dompdf. I've changed the directory in the config/dompdf.php, also the font_cache to public/fonts/. But I'm not able to display the font in my PDF.

Several offered solutions in the internet doesn't help me. I can't find the problem, respectively the way how to import my font. I tried different fonts like Lato or Roboto, but always the same.

Changes in the config/dompdf.php

```php
        "font_dir" => storage_path('public/fonts/'), 

        "font_cache" => storage_path('public/fonts/'),
```

The controller function:

```php
    public function deliveryDetailsPDF($delivery_id){

        $header   = Delivery::where('id',$delivery_id)->first();
        $details  = Delivery::getDeliveryDetails($delivery_id);

        $pdf = \PDF::setOptions([
                      'isHtml5ParserEnabled'=> true,
                      'isRemoteEnabled' => true,
                    ])
                    ->loadView('delivery.pdf',compact('header','details'))
                    ->stream();


        return $pdf;
    }
```

Style block in the header of the Blade file delivery/pdf.blade.php:

```html
  <style>
    @font-face{
        font-family: VAGBlack;
        src:url('/fonts/VAGRounded_BT.ttf');
        /* src:url({{ storage_path('fonts\VAGRounded_BT.ttf') }}) format("truetype"); */
    }


    h1, h2 {
      font-family:VAGBlack;
      font-size: 14pt;
      color:black;
    }
    </style>
```

In the generated PDF is still Arial used. 
How could I reach my goal?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to be a bit more explicit in your `@font-face` declaration. Try the following:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: VAGBlack;
    src: url('/fonts/VAGRounded_BT.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I specified a bold font weight because that is how h1 and h2 elements are styled. If you don't specify the weight and style:

- I'm not sure Dompdf would register the font.
- Even if Dompdf did register the font it wouldn't use it on the H1 and H2 elements since it's not registered for use with bold text.